# How to add enter key event on a button

Tags: c#, xaml, button, windows-8.1

I have a button in XAML here:

```
<Button Content="Login" x:Name="loginButton" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="3"
        Margin="200,30,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="50" Width="150"
        VertialAlignment="Top" Click="loginButton_Click" ClickMode="Press"
        FontSize="24" FontFamily="Calibri" Style="{StaticResource AlbaabButtonStyle}">
</Button>
```

When user hits the enter key, he must be logged in to his account. How do I generate a press enter key event in c#?

Answer (score 2):

Set [`Button.IsDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.isdefault%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to *true* then just handle the button click event.Pressing `ENTER` will trigger your default button's click event after you set `IsDefault` true..